# Android Force Close because of SeekBar element

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

```
E/AndroidRuntime(7183): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SeekBar     cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

is this true? 
if you can't use a seekbar to change text in a EditText element then what should i use? 
a static TextView? 
because i need a slider aka SeekBar for my app
thanks in advance

here's the code

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    // update currentCustomPercent, then call updateCustom
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        // sets currentCustomPercent to position of seekBars's thumb
        currentCustomPercent = seekBar.getProgress();
        updateCustom(); // updates EditTexts  for custom part and Total
    } // end method on progressChanged

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    } // end method onStartTrackingTouch

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }

}; // end onSeekBarChangeListener
```

the program doesn't error but it force closes... and the logcat say's that this is screwed up.. 6 hours worth of work... down the toilet... #flush

Comment: Your question is not clear. why would you want to use a seekbar to change text in a EditText ?

Comment: the seekBar element creates a custom value to calculate.. based on percentage like a certain percentage discount and displays in a EditText element...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are casting seekBarobject to editText in method:

```
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
```

If yes, just do the following:

```
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
{
    editText.setText(""+progress);
}
```

Comment: you're answer gives me this.. Cannot invoke setText(String) on the primitive type int

Comment: not actually, if you use editText.setText(int), it search for resource with id in parameter in method.